# Raw pasta on Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, chagim-holidays

How can raw pasta be considered chametz on Pesach if it is not fit for consumption (אינו ראוי לאכילת כלב)?

Comment: What is your proof that a dog won't eat it? I've eaten it in the past!

Comment: Assuming you are correct (and non-spoilt dogs are not very fussy - dog food looks a lot like raw pasta (dry and crunchy) and smells worse) it's probably because it can become edible. Otherwise, frozen foods would also not be considered chametz. Nor flour made from washed wheat.

Comment: If something is presently unfit for eating, the fact that it technically could become edible should not make it assur.

Comment: According to the CDC it is not safe to eat raw pasta.

Comment: The CDC also thinks raw dough is not safe to eat

Comment: That's a good point